# Search engine, asp.net mvc, Domain Driven Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, domain-driven-design

Going to develop a search engine.

I'm wondering how my DDD should look. Sorting records should be implemented, but i don't want that my views knew about my database structure (by which columns to sort). As far as i understand - sorting information should come from infrastructure layer, from repository implementation, so there have to be a flexible domain.

How it should look?

I want this to be strongly typed.

Any best practices?

Recommendations for architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to develop a search engine, you'll be forced to think about scalability very fast. Sorting in search related environments is a familiar problem. You should have a look at the search implementations from Google! How you sort should depend on a [ranking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank). A domain centric ranking algorithm design shouldn't be such different from the  ranking as a service approach!

What language you use is your choise. If you'll choose C/C++ [Message Passing Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) (MPI) for distributed computing. If you use Java, have a look at [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) and [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com/) (GridGain implements Googles MapReduce).

Another question is, how to store your data (distributed, fast, fault-tolerant)! For Java have a look at [Project Voldemord](http://project-voldemort.com/) (which is one of the best systems you can get for free.

For more information about the Google architecture, read more on [the high scalability website](http://highscalability.com/google-architecture).

For issues about DDD, have a look at [dddcommunity.org](http://dddcommunity.org/), the Homepage of Eric Evans himself ;) He has written a very good Book [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215). DDD is fine, because it assures the integrity and the of a Domain.

A simple model might be:

```
page ( URL url, BigInt rank, List<String> keywords, 
       List<URL> links, List<URL> outLinks, Content ref) 


content ( GzippedBytes[] content )
```

If a new node is added to the system, it should react on things like "*setLinks*" etc. so it can get it's pagerank by it's own.

The client ist quient simple, he does only a *search ( keywords )* which gets sorted by PageRank.

Here is an **service** [example of a pagerank implementation](http://www.kyle-brady.com/2009/03/07/google-pagerank-a-simple-implementation-in-java/) in Java.

Comment: With search engine i did not mean web crawler/indexer. It`s supposed to be ordinary search mechanism over specified business objects.

Comment: Current search method has this signature:

Get(string searchColumn, string query, string orderExpr, int startIndex, int maxRows, bool useRanks, int authorRank, int titleRank, int otherRank).

Comment: I don`t know how to ensure, that UI layer knows nothing about database structure yet can sort result page. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basics to a custom search engine that parses MVC View directories, reads the files and matches the supplied text with a regular expression.  My site returns html links of the search results.  This code will result in the creation of a list.

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo  (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToSearchableViews"]);
//get all view directories except the shared
foreach (DirectoryInfo d in di.GetDirectories().Where(d=>d.Name != "Shared"))
{
    //get all the .cshtml files
    foreach (FileInfo fi in d.GetFiles().Where(e=>e.Extension  == ".cshtml"))
    {
    //check if cshtml file and exclude partial pages
    if (fi.Name.Substring(0,1) != "_")
    {
        MatchCollection matches;
        bool foundMatch = false;
        int matchCount = 0;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
        {
            string file = sr.ReadToEnd();
            foreach (string word in terms)
            {
                Regex exp = new Regex("(?i)" + word.Trim() + "(?-i)");
                matches = exp.Matches(file);
                if (matches.Count > 0)
                {
                    foundMatch = true;
                    matchCount = matches.Count;
                }
            }
         //check match count and create links
         //
         //
         }
      }
      }
  }
  return results;
```